# Visual application form designer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

just a quick question here concerning Visual Studios 2015, for C++ is there a visual designer for forms or is it purely code?

If there is could someone direct me towards the correct path. I would prefer not to use Microsofts version of C++ but if that's the only method then I'll have to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use QT (https://www.qt.io/) which connects to visual studio using a Signal/Slot mechanism. I've got some easy examples here: https://github.com/fweidner/QtExamples

Edit: There is also a VisualStudioPlugin for Qt:  (doc-snapshots.qt.io/vstools-2.0/index.html)

Comment: thank you, i'll take a look now